# Is there any way to create same name of multiple fields like name="fieldName[ ]" in redux form?

Tags: regex, excel, reactjs, filereader, redux-form

I am working on a scenario I am selecting an excel file and validating it, though my custom regex and validation rules . after validating I need to get a preview of that file in the table I am doing all these scenarios very well.  but here is the problem where on the specific index of column or row where excel file regex fails there should be either a text box or Combobox. it will be conditional on every column like if the email is invalid there should be an email input box soo that the user can correct it, on the other side of the user adds some invalid city that is not in DB there should be Combobox of cities soo that he can select valid one.

Here is the code that i am using to read and validating the file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import RenderSelectInput from "../UI/select";
import InputComponent from "../UI/input";
import ImageUploaderComp from "../UI/imageUploader";

import {
  getcities,
  getmunit,
  getstypes
} from "../../redux/actions/comboAction";
import XLSX from "xlsx";
// reactstrap components
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardFooter,
  Badge,
  Button,
  CardBody,
  FormGroup,
  Form,
  Input,
  Container,
  CardTitle,
  CardText,
  Row,
  Col,
  Alert,
  UncontrolledAlert,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  Media,
  Pagination,
  PaginationItem,
  PaginationLink,
  Progress,
  Table,
  UncontrolledTooltip
} from "reactstrap";
// core components
import Header from "components/Headers/Header.js";
import { $CombinedState } from "redux";
class ExcelBook extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    ErrorMsg: null,
    SuccessMsg: null,
    isExcelLoaded: false,
    isExcelLoading: false,
    excelFileData: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.reduxStore.cities.fetchedCities.docs.length <= 0) {
      this.props.getAllCities();
    }
    if (this.props.reduxStore.munit.fetchedMunit.docs.length <= 0) {
      this.props.getAllmunits();
    }

    if (this.props.reduxStore.stypes.fetchedStypes.docs.length <= 0) {
      this.props.getAllstypes();
    }
  }
  fileProcess = async e => {
    try {
      let contentBuffer = await this.onchangeHanglerExcelFile(e);
      console.log(contentBuffer);
      this.setState({
        excelFileData: contentBuffer,
        isExcelLoading: false,
        isExcelLoaded: true
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  onchangeHanglerExcelFile = e => {
    this.setState({
      isExcelLoading: true
    });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const cities = this.props.reduxStore.cities.fetchedCities.docs;

      const shipmentTypes = this.props.reduxStore.stypes.fetchedStypes.docs;
      const munits = this.props.reduxStore.munit.fetchedMunit.docs;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      let excelData = [];
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
        var wb = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });

        var first_worksheet = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];
        var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(first_worksheet, {
          header: 1
        });

        let i;
        let j;
        let k;
        let l;

        const comparedWithCities = [];
        const comparedWithShipmentTypes = [];
        const compareWithMunits = [];
        for (j = 0; j < cities.length; j++) {
          comparedWithCities.push(cities[j].cityName);
        }
        for (k = 0; k < shipmentTypes.length; k++) {
          comparedWithShipmentTypes.push(shipmentTypes[k].shipmentType);
        }
        for (l = 0; l < munits.length; l++) {
          compareWithMunits.push(munits[l].unit);
        }

        for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
          const excelRowObject = {};

          excelRowObject["cName"] = data[i][0];

          if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(data[i][1])) {
            excelRowObject["cEmail"] = false;
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cEmail"] = data[i][1];
          }
          if (!/^3[0-9+]{9}$/i.test(data[i][2])) {
            excelRowObject["cPhone"] = false;
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cPhone"] = data[i][2];
          }

          if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _/#&+-||]{25,}$/i.test(data[i][3])) {
            excelRowObject["cAddress"] = false;
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cAddress"] = data[i][3];
          }
          const ccity = data[i][4].replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
          const capitalCity = ccity.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ccity.slice(1);

          if (comparedWithCities.includes(capitalCity) === false) {
            excelRowObject["cCity"] = false;
          } else {
            const ccity = data[i][4].replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
            const capitalCity = ccity.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ccity.slice(1);
            excelRowObject["cCity"] = capitalCity;
          }

          if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(data[i][5])) {
            excelRowObject["cAmount"] = false;
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cAmount"] = data[i][5];
          }
          excelRowObject["productDescription"] = data[i][6];
          excelRowObject["cWeight"] = data[i][7];

          const cstype = data[i][8].replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
          const capitalStype = cstype.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cstype.slice(1);
          if (comparedWithShipmentTypes.includes(capitalStype) === false) {
            excelRowObject["cStypes"] = false;
          } else {
            const cstype = data[i][8].replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
            const capitalStype =
              cstype.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + cstype.slice(1);
            excelRowObject["cStypes"] = capitalStype;
          }
          if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(data[i][9])) {
            excelRowObject["cPieces"] = false;
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cPieces"] = data[i][9];
          }
          if (
            data[i][10] === "Y" ||
            data[i][10] === "N" ||
            data[i][10] === "y" ||
            data[i][10] === "n"
          ) {
            excelRowObject["cFragile"] = data[i][10];
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cFragile"] = false;
          }
          const dimentionArr = data[i][11].split(",");

          const munit = dimentionArr[0].replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
          const capitalMunit = munit.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + munit.slice(1);

          if (compareWithMunits.includes(capitalMunit) === false) {
            excelRowObject["cMunit"] = false;
          } else {
            const munit = dimentionArr[0].replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
            const capitalMunit = munit.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + munit.slice(1);
            excelRowObject["cMunit"] = capitalMunit;
          }
          if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(dimentionArr[1])) {
            excelRowObject["cHeight"] = false;
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cHeight"] = dimentionArr[1];
          }
          if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(dimentionArr[2])) {
            excelRowObject["cWidth"] = false;
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cWidth"] = dimentionArr[2];
          }
          if (!/^[0-9]*$/.test(dimentionArr[3])) {
            excelRowObject["cLength"] = false;
          } else {
            excelRowObject["cLength"] = dimentionArr[3];
          }

          excelData.push(excelRowObject);
        }
        resolve(excelData);
      };
      reader.onerror = reject;
    });
  };
  handleSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  renderName = ({ fields, meta: { submitFailed, error } }) => (
    <div>
      {fields.map((name, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <Field
            component={InputComponent}
            className="form-control-alternative"
            name={`${name}.consigneName`}
            type="text"
            id="input-consigneeName"
            placeholder="Consginee Name"
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, isSendingRequest } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <Header
          pageType="innerPage"
          headerClass="header bg-gradient-success pb-8 pt-5 pt-md-8"
        />
        {/* Page content */}
        <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
          {/* Table */}
          <Row>
            <div className="col">
              <Card className="shadow">
                <CardHeader className="border-0">
                  <h3 className="mb-0">Excel Booking</h3>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody align="center">
                  <CardTitle>
                    Book your packet according to the sample provided below,
                    supported file types are <br />
                    <b style={{ color: "green" }}>(CSV , XLSX , XLS)</b>
                  </CardTitle>

                  <Button
                    className="btn-icon btn-3"
                    color="primary"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={this.onclickHandler}
                  >
                    <span className="btn-inner--icon">
                      <i className="fa fa-download" />
                    </span>
                    <span className="btn-inner--text">Sample File</span>
                  </Button>

                  <Button
                    className="btn-icon btn-3"
                    color="success"
                    type="button"
                  >
                    <span className="btn-inner--icon">
                      <i className="fa fa-upload" />
                    </span>
                    <span className="btn-inner--text">Upload Excel</span>
                  </Button>
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    onChange={value => this.fileProcess(value)}
                  ></input>
                  <div id="wrapper"></div>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </Row>

          <Row>
            <div className="col">
              <Card className="shadow">
                <CardHeader className="border-0">
                  <h3 className="mb-0">PREVIEW</h3>
                </CardHeader>
                <Form
                  encType="multipart/form-data"
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}
                >
                  <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
                    <thead className="thead-light">
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Consignee Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Consignee Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Consginee Phone</th>
                        <th scope="col">Consginee Address</th>
                        <th scope="col">Designation City</th>
                        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product Desciption</th>
                        <th scope="col">Weight</th>
                        <th scope="col">Shipment Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Pieces</th>
                        <th scope="col">Fragile</th>
                        <th scope="col">Unit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Height</th>
                        <th scope="col">Width</th>
                        <th scope="col">Length</th>

                        <th scope="col" />
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.state.isExcelLoaded &&
                      this.state.isExcelLoading === false ? (
                        this.state.excelFileData.map((p, index) => {
                          return (
                            <tr key={index}>
                              <td>{p.cName}</td>
                              <td>{p.cEmail}</td>
                              <td>{p.cPhone}</td>
                              <td>{p.cAddress}</td>
                              <td>{p.cCity}</td>
                              <td>{p.cAmount}</td>
                              <td>{p.productDescription}</td>
                              <td>{p.cWeight}</td>
                              <td>{p.cStypes}</td>
                              <td>{p.cPieces}</td>
                              <td>{p.cFragile}</td>
                              <td>{p.cMunit}</td>
                              <td>{p.cHeight}</td>
                              <td>{p.cWidth}</td>
                              <td>{p.cLength}</td>
                            </tr>
                          );
                        })
                      ) : (
                        <tr>
                          <td>Select File</td>
                        </tr>
                      )}
                    </tbody>
                  </Table>
                  <Button type="submit"></Button>
                </Form>
                <CardFooter className="py-4"></CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    reduxStore: state
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getAllCities: () => {
      dispatch(getcities());
    },
    getAllmunits: () => {
      dispatch(getmunit());
    },
    getAllstypes: () => {
      dispatch(getstypes());
    }
  };
};
ExcelBook = reduxForm({
  form: "excelBooking",

})(ExcelBook);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExcelBook);
```

this is the excel file i am trying to upload :

[image: excel file screenshot i am using]

this is preview i got after validating and processing excel file clientside 
note where you see empty spaces are failed validation

[image: result after upload]

this is the response that i am looping through and rendering it in my dom for preview, note the fields those are false are failed validation & each object in this array is a row.

[image: response preview]

i tried my best to demonstrate my problem. according to my vission response is generated already main focus is to conditionally render fields using redux-form i also use and wrap my head around fieldarray but i am not able to crack this situation with it.

Comment: Did you check FormArray? https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/

Comment: I already wrapped my head around but I didn't find a solution with it because I am looping through my state and if I pass <FieldArray /> it will create similar multiple arrays and in my scenarios they are useless.. you can check if anything possible which that according to my knowledge and experience I tried my best

Comment: Do you want to have input `TextField`, `Combobox` inside your table `td` tag? and it only availabe if input from excel is not valid?

Comment: exactly like for some column I need text box and for some, I will populate combo accordingly in td tag I can define manually where to define combo or text . you got the point

Comment: How about control the input value manually, it 100% will works, you can control the value, type of input manually. If you cannot find any better sulution, you can done it manually

Comment: can you please brief me more on that? you are saying to go without redux form?

Comment: yes that's my idea, because some line you have input, some line does not. it's complicated to control the data that need to update. Do you agree? If so, I will tell your more about the way to do that

Comment: yes tell me you can see my code for reference and please collaborate me regarding that if possible sir

Comment: Example: `name` in row 2 need to edit - TextField, `grops` in row 3 need to edit - ComboBox, show the TextField/ComboBox component, with event onChange to an `onChangeField` function. This function receive(rowIndex, fieldName, newValue). Inside this function, you use `find` or `findIndex` to find the record that need to update in `this.state.excelFileData`, then update the `fieldName` with `newValue` it, and `setState` again

Comment: It hard to post an demo code here. If you cannot understand, I will post it in the answer area

Comment: post it bro in answer

Comment: Please stop posting anything in all CAPS. It's considered shouting.

Comment: sorry if it bothers i just try to clarify :-(

Comment: I've made a demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-jackson-h80q8
You can use that flow in your code

Comment: bro i wrap my head around your code you just simplify it and brief me very well really appreciatable, but one thing my question is after editing all the data. final object will submit as post request to an API for submitting soo tell me how can I wrap the final table in a form and get values respectively..if you have time kindly demonstrate that thanks because there are various fields of same name attribute how can I do that any idea please

Comment: hey buddy i just made eveything with your idea i code and it works i need to ask something and letme complete this answer please

Comment: i need validation for every field is that posible ? i tried alot but it same for every field having name cname but i have different fields i need validation for every field seperately if user enters wrong email then there should be red onblur of text box